# Firefox an IE displaying css code differently to Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

So on my website I have css role over buttons, and everything displays as it should in Chrom but in IE and Firefox the height is larger so you can see too much of the image.
Here's the website its happening on http://www.dillonbrannick.com/ I'm just focusing on one of the buttons, but it is happening with all 4 of them.

Here's the code that effects the home button.

Inside the body and nav tags

```
<nav class="body">

<div class="links nav" id="home-nav">
<a href="#"
onclick=" toggle_visibility_1('illustrations'); toggle_visibility_1('illustration-sub'); toggle_visibility_1('painting-sub'); toggle_visibility_1('paintings'); toggle_visibility_1('animation'); toggle_visibility_1('contact'); toggle_visibility_1('box'); toggle_visibility_2('homeimage'); toggle_visibility_2('homebio'); toggle_visibility_2('facebook'); toggle_visibility_2('google');">
</a>
</div>

</nav>
```

I'd imagine the Javascript doesn't effect it as all it does is diplay on/off elements so it has nothing to do with dimensions.

here's the css:

```
.body{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
}
nav{
    margin: -125px 0 0 -44.5px;
}
.nav{
    position:absolute;
    width: 89px;
}
.nav a{
    height: 107.5px;
}
.links a{
   display: block;
   margin: auto auto auto auto;
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: transparent solid 0px;
}
#home-nav {
    margin: -60px 0px 0px -140px;
}
#home-nav a{          
   background: url('http://dl.dropbox.com/u/70582811/home.link.png') no-repeat left top;
}
#home-nav a:hover{
    background-position: left -107.5px;
}
```

I know the body class probably doesn't make any difference to the problem, but I just wanted to show everything that effects the button.

As you can see in these two images(left:Chrome, right: IE and Firefox). There is blue appearing just underneath the grey bar that shouldn't be there, that is part of the other half of the image that is then shifted up onrollover. As you can see on my [website](http://www.dillonbrannick.com/).
[image: Chrome]   [image: IE and Firefox]
Thanks in advance,
Dillon Brannick.

Comment: Why are you trying to use fractional pixels in your CSS? E.g. `.nav a{height: 107.5px;}`

Comment: The size of the whole image is 215, and when I was putting my two graphics together I didn't think about the .5px that I'd get when divided by 2 and didn't really care because why would it matter? and I like the size as it is so I never considered changing it, on the other hand if it is the reason, I'd be able to change it.

Comment: Try making it just 107. Browsers can't render fractional pixels and the rounding it induces could be the cause of your problems.

Comment: I am gonna take a wild guess it has something to do with the 0.5 pixel

Comment: Thanks guys that's what the problem was, silly me just assumed it wouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the use of .5

```
.nav a{
    height: 107.5px;
}
```

Browsers probably handle that differently. I don't think there exists something like half a pixel.

Edit : just try 107px, and then 108px. I think one of them should give u the desired result. 107px probably. Firefox takes 107.5px as 108px.

Comment: Yes, firebug shows the (computed/actual) height as 108, while chrome dev tools shows it as 107

Comment: Yes! I guess I've learnt my lesson never use .5px. Also I should get firebug and then use it. For now I've changed it 107 leaving the graphic as is but I'll make it the proper size soon. Thanks, now I can take away the 'for best viewing use chrome'.

Comment: I don't see a reason why you should change the graphic :)

Comment: well okay, but I don't have it set perfectly in the middle so when you roolover it moves slightly

Comment: Ah ok, I thought that it was supposed to do that. Doesn't look bad. :D

Comment: Yeah I was just about to say, it doesn't look bad at all actually kinda adds to it I'll leave so save me the hassle as well.